# How to connect to a remote node from NodeJS?

Tags: daemon

I'm trying to figure out how to connect my NodeJS app to a remote monero node. I need it to query the network.

Here's is the list of available JSON-RPC methods — [Daemon RPC documentation](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html)

Here's the list of open nodes  — https://moneroworld.com/

**Here's what I do:**

```
const rpc = require('json-rpc-client')
const host = 'node.moneroworld.com'
const port = '18089'
const client = new rpc({ host, port })
client.connect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

**Here's the error:**

```
{ host: 'node.moneroworld.com', port: '18089' }
error:Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND node.moneroworld.com node.moneroworld.com:18089
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND node.moneroworld.com node.moneroworld.com:18089
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'node.moneroworld.com',
  host: 'node.moneroworld.com',
  port: '18089' }
```

**When I use another host:**

```
const host = 'node.xmrbackb.one'
const port = '18081'
```

**I get:**

```
{ host: 'node.xmrbackb.one', port: '18081' }
error:Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 116.93.119.79:18081
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 116.93.119.79:18081
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1057:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1096:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '116.93.119.79',
  port: 18081 }
```

I can't event connect to a node. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution, using `monero-rpc-client` library. When I use `node.moneroworld.com:18089` as host, the code doesn't work. When **ip** is used instead everything is OK. The **ip** is taken from [here](http://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=node.moneroworld.com).

```
const rpcClientClass = require('monero-rpc-client')
const nodeAddress = 'http://62.210.124.152:18089'
const rpcClient = new rpcClientClass(nodeAddress)
rpcClient.getBlockCount()
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

**Here's the result:**

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "count": 1492683,
    "status": "OK"
  }
}
```