# Can I use testnet open node for making rpc requests about testnet? If yes, what am I doing wrong (trying to get block height)?

Tags: rpc, javascript, api

I'm exploring what APIs are available to explore mainnet and testnet and a small task I'm trying to do is to get block height of testnet.

[Docs](https://monerodocs.org/infrastructure/networks/) about networks tell that there's a testnet open node: `monero-testnet.exan.tech:28081`.

Looking at the basic example of [monero-javascript](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript), I see that the following code should probably be enough:

```
// import library
const monerojs = require("monero-javascript");

// inside an async function
const daemon = await monerojs.connectToDaemonRpc("http://localhost:38081", "superuser", "abctesting123");
const height = await daemon.getHeight();
```

Well, I'm not sure about login and passphrase, but I tried

```
const daemon = await monerojs.connectToDaemonRpc("http://monero-testnet.exan.tech:28081", "superuser", "abctesting123");
```

and got

> TypeError: The URL must be of scheme file

(same for `http://monero-testnet.exan.tech:28081/json_rpc`)

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is `monero-testnet.exan.tech:28081` an endpoint for json-rpc? Are json-rpc and [daemon-rpc](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_count) the same? Is there a public endpoint that I can use with `monerojs.connectToDaemonRpc` at all? In fact any pointer to get block height via some public API is welcome.

Comment: Start by using a node that's online: https://monero.fail/?nettype=testnet

Comment: @jtgrassie thanks, I've figured that already, will post the overall solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution I've come up with is based on [this QA](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/7388/14510) (actually, almost a copy-paste):

```
const RpcClientClass = require("monero-rpc-client");
const nodeAddress = ... // see nodes at https://monero.fail for quick dev
const rpcClient = new RpcClientClass(nodeAddress);
rpcClient.getBlockCount()
    .then(result => console.log(result.result.count));
```

This is an example of JSON RPC call of one of the [daemon-rpc](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the original code working on my system and fix the

```
TypeError: The URL must be of scheme file
```

error by switching to WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) before running the code
and updating to latest node version